# Proof of the fundamental theorem of algebra

Tags: complex-analysis

Is the following proof correct?

Let $p(z)$ be a nonconstant polynomial, and by contradiction suppose it has no zeroes.  Then $f(z) = 1/p(z)$ is an entire function.  By Liouville, $p(z)$ is unbounded, so $p(z) \to \infty$ as $|z| \to \infty$, and so $f(z) \to 0$ as $|z| \to \infty$.  By definition, there exists $M > 0$ such that $f(z) < 1$ for $|z| > M$, and of course $f$ is bounded on the compact disk $|z| \le M \implies f$ is bounded in the entire plane $\implies$ $f$ is constant $\implies p(z)$ is constant.

Comment: Yes, this proof is correct. It's standard to prove the fundamental theorem of algebra after seeing Liouville's theorem for the first time.

Comment: It should be noted that while this (and other related) proofs are very slick (and cool), there is a very elementary and straightforward proof that involved no sophisticated concepts at all (and the proof is short as well).

Answer (score 2):

Just a minuscule problem. $p(z) \to \infty$, as $z \to \infty$ because the leading term of the coefficient dominates, not because Liouville. Being unbounded is not the same as approaching $\infty$ in modulus. For instance, $1/z$ is unbounded but $1/z \to 0$ as $z \to \infty$.

Comment: Well, $1/z$ is not entire. But $e^z$ is entire and unbounded, but as $z\to\infty$, it is not true that $e^z\to\infty$. For example, $e^{k\cdot 2\pi i}=1$.